# Why are the vote buttons no longer clickable?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I spy in Firebug's HTML panel:

```
<div class="vote"><!-- other children omitted for brevity -->
    <a title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" class="vote-up-off">up vote</a>
</div>
```

Note that the `a` has no `href` attribute. I remember not too long ago that [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/index)'s hint mode would detect vote buttons, for instance I could type `gg f up vote 1` to vote up the question.

This is no longer the case. It seems like the vote anchors recently lost their `href` attribute (or something else happened that made the buttons no longer appear as "clickable" to Pentadactyl). Why is this?

I managed to work around the problem with a bookmarklet that adds `href="#"` to all vote buttons, but I'd like to know the reasoning behind this design choice. I suppose it's bad practice to set the `href` attribute if the anchor isn't supposed to send the browser to another page, but why not use `<button>`s instead, as demonstrated by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emlun/9dLaG/)? After all, that's what `<button>`s are for.

Comment: Really, the anchor should be a `<button type="button">` (or, if SO was going to bother with unobtrusive JS, a form with a submit button).

Comment: @Quentin Yep, and intercept the submit event if JS is available. :)

Answer (score 7):

I am not an SO developer but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167175/2591612):

> In HTML5, using an a element without an href attribute is valid. It is
>   considered to be a "placeholder hyperlink."

It seems perfectly valid even if it breaks your tool.

EDIT: One problem is that the vote up/down buttons are not keyboard focusable with the missing `href` portion. Adding in the `href=#` could add unnecessarily to the browser history. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885150/2591612) suggests the following:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: Sure it's valid, but it's not semantic.

Comment: @Stijn: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: *Semantic* means using the right HTML element, not just using valid HTML. For example, you can use `<div id="footer">` which is perfectly valid, but the right element would be `<footer>`. Here, we vote by clicking on buttons, so `<button>` is the right element.

Comment: @Stijn: Understood and I can see your point. Someone from SO is going to have to chime in because its hard to know the intent.

Comment: Wasn't an `a` element without the `href` valid in HTML4 as well? As in that `<a name="1337"/>` would give you an *anchor* for the browser to go to when given an URL ending with `#1337`.

Comment: @EmilLundberg: I am not sure in HTML4 whether it makes the browser do as you describe but from what I have read it is valid in HTML4 also. But seems to break screen readers and apparently this tool that lets you do fancy things in Firefox with the keyboard.

Comment: @EmilLundberg That is true, but it would have to have a `name` then. Nowadays, this is replaced by the `id`, and in fact any element that has an `id` is an anchor. [try it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265178/why-are-the-vote-buttons-no-longer-clickable?cb=1#footer). :)

Comment: `It seems perfectly valid even if it breaks your tool` that's what she said.